# incompatible types: <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, onclicklistener, interstitial

when i run app it gives the following error

```
incompatible types: <anonymous OnClickListener> cannot be converted to Context
                InterstitialAd.load(this,ForexScalping.this.getString(R.string.main_inter), adRequest,
```

im still new to code so i have no clue.
here is the java file

```
public class ForexScalping extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button2;

    private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if (mInterstitialAd != null)
        {
            mInterstitialAd.show(ForexScalping.this);
            return;
        }
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_forex_scalping);

        this.button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(ForexScalping.this);
                pd.setCancelable(false);
                pd.setMessage("Loading...");
                pd.show();
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

                InterstitialAd.load(this,ForexScalping.this.getString(R.string.main_inter), adRequest,
                        new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                                // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                                // an ad is loaded.
                                mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                                mInterstitialAd.show(ForexScalping.this);
                            }
```

I have tried adding the View.OnClicklistener to the public but still it brings the same error .
and yes I have tried all the answers given on errors related to this.

Answer (score 0):

remove **this** from InterstitialAd.load(**this**,ForexScalping.this.getString with **ForexScalping.this**